# browsercheck with "is not" rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

i have this working code

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9){
}
else{
    $('.insert_checkpassword').toggle($('#password').val().length > 0);
}
```

is it possible to do this smaller?

i want do to this code for all browser but not ie smaller version 9

someting like this

```
if IS NOT ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9){
    $('.insert_checkpassword').toggle($('#password').val().length > 0);
}
```

Comment: `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!`

Comment: Why do you need to check IE's version? What are you trying to avoid?

Comment: `if(!($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9))`

Comment: The opposite of `< 9` is obviously `>= 9`

Comment: $.browser is deprecated, you are advised to use $.supports or anothe r feature detection mechanism

From jquery docs... 
Rather than using $.browser to detect the current user agent and alter the page presentation based on which browser is running, it is a good practice to use feature detection. To make this process simpler, jQuery performs many such tests and sets properties of the jQuery.support object.

Comment: thanks @jAndy i know it is a one of your "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" just forget the bracket :(

Comment: **Please** try to avoid using browser checks. jQuery has deprecated `$.browser` for a long time because it's considered bad practice, and the most recent versions of jQuery removed it entirely. You should consider using feature detection instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [**logical not operator**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9) `!`, you can read more about logical operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

```
if (!( $.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9)){
    $('.insert_checkpassword').toggle($('#password').val().length > 0);
}
```

Comment: probably add a link to some basic ecmascript tutorial.

Comment: damn.. i forgot the bracket before ! :(

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
if (!$.browser.msie || parseInt($.browser.version, 10) >= 9) {
    $('.insert_checkpassword').toggle($('#password').val().length > 0);
}
```

Note that `$.browser` is deprecated and shouldn't be relied upon.